# Use Octokit to retrieve private repositories from organizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, github-api, octokit

I'm trying to retrieve all repositories from a certain user's organization using the Octokit gem for ruby.

I have this client variable:

```
@client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: TOKEN)
```

And when I use this:

```
@client.repos
```

I'm able to retrieve all repositories of the user (EVEN THE PRIVATE ONES FROM THE ORGANIZATIONS)

But with this

```
@client.repos(some_org_id)
```

I'm only getting the public ones from the some_org_id organization.

My OAuth token scope is set with the permissions:

```
repo, user, read:org
```

Am I missing something here? The [API Documentaion](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories) mentions that the default value of repos privacy is `all`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I was able to get the private repos doing the following:

```
@client.org_repos(some_repo_id)
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

According to [**this**](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/pengwynn/octokit/Octokit/Client/Organizations#organization_repositories-instance_method) documentation:

`client.org_repos('org_name', {:type => 'all'})`

to get all repos at once and not just one. Then you can iterate through it with a loop.